# Odd error on cfquery while creating view

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have the following query that's returning the error:  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'."  I've tried to find any reference of this instance online and in SO. If I overlooked a solution or if anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it.

Query:

```
    <cfquery datasource="#mydatasource#">
    CREATE VIEW #arguments.bulkRow.request_by#_uploader_features_view
    (
        feature_products_id
        , feature_text
        , feature_priority
    )
    AS
    SELECT
        a1.tbl_products__products_id AS feature_products_id,
        a1.tbl_productfeature__feature_text__1 AS feature_text,
        1 AS feature_priority
    FROM bulk_product_upload a1
    WHERE processed = 0
        AND request_by = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.bulkRow.request_by#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        AND LEN( a1.tbl_productfeature__feature_text__1 ) > 1

    UNION

    SELECT
        a1.tbl_products__products_id AS feature_products_id,
        a1.tbl_productfeature__feature_text__2 AS feature_text,
        2 AS feature_priority
    FROM bulk_product_upload a1
    WHERE processed = 0
        AND request_by = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.bulkRow.request_by#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        AND LEN(a1.tbl_productfeature__feature_text__2) > 1   

    ...

    UNION

    SELECT
        a1.tbl_products__products_id AS feature_products_id,
        a1.tbl_productfeature__feature_text__20 AS feature_text,
        2 AS feature_priority
    FROM bulk_product_upload a1
    WHERE processed = 0
        AND request_by = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.bulkRow.request_by#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        AND LEN(a1.tbl_productfeature__feature_text__20) > 1
</cfquery>
```

This is an abbreviated form of the query but it should get you started and show the basic layout.

Thanks in advance,

JP

Comment: What is the value of the `arguments.bulkRow.request_by` variable?

Comment: Just prior to the cfquery call, cfdump out the #arguments.bulkRow.request_by# variable. I have a feeling you are expecting it to be a string, which will help form the dynamic name of your view--but it is something else entirely, causing the SQL error (ie. it ends up being something like CREATE VIEW a phrase with spaces in it_uploader_features_view)

Comment: @JustinScott - it's the user_id.. for example you can say "i_jimp".

Comment: Also, the detailed exception information should include the full SQL query that ColdFusion is passing to the SQL server along with the full error information that SQL server is returning.  Posting that information in the question might also be helpful.

Comment: Message:  [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.

NextException Message: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Comment: As a debugging method, change the first line to this: `CREATE VIEW i_jimp_uploader_features_view` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you even use `cfqueryparam` here?

Comment: @AlEverett I don't believe he is use cfqueryparam in the create view section, so it should (in theory) work.

Comment: I guess, based on the accepted answer, that I was right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran some testing against my own SQL Server and it appears that parameterized queries cause problems when creating views.  Removing the CFQUERYPARAM tags should correct the issue.  Using CFQUERYPARAM with a standard select statement is a best practice, but in this case you're passing in SQL that will be executed every time the view is accessed, so the parameterization isn't able to get passed through into the view.

Here are a couple of examples using the same concept, but tables from one of my own databases.

The following produces the `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'` error:

```
<cfset id="x" />
<cfquery>
    create view #id#_view as
    select * from AdminUser
    where admID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#id#" />
</cfquery>
```

The following works fine:

```
<cfset id="y" />
<cfquery>
    create view #id#_view as
    select * from AdminUser
    where admID = '#id#'
</cfquery>
```

If anyone is able to locate a SQL Server reference which explains this in detail, feel free to edit this answer with a link.

I would also note that depending on the value of the ID, you might consider wrapping the view name with brackets.  If the ID begins with a number the statement will fail as-is, but putting that into a bracketed statement will cover those situations (just be sure to use the bracket notation when querying the view as well).  Example: `create view [#id#_view]`